# Cycles Per Element V.S. actual performance of Polynomial Evaluation

Tags: c++, performance, optimization

In the book "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective (3rd edition)"'s chapter 5, exercise 5.5 and 5.6 talked about Polynomial Evaluation:

[image: Polynomial Evaluation]

It also gives two implementation `poly()` and `polyh()`, and says `poly()`'s CPE(Cycles Per Element) is 5.0 and `polyh()`'s CPE is 8.0, thus concludes `poly()` run faster than `polyh()`. **But with clang-12 or clang-14 on my ubuntu20.04, `polyh()` is much faster, instead of what these exercises said. I'm confused. **

The Polynomial Evaluation implementations:

```cpp
// the naive method
double poly(double a[], double x, long degree)
{
    long i;
    double result = a[0];
    double xpwr = x;
    for (i = 1; i <= degree; i++)
    {
        result += a[i] * xpwr;
        xpwr = x * xpwr;
    }
    return result;
}

// the Horner's method
double polyh(double a[], double x, long degree)
{
    long i;
    double result = a[degree];
    for (i = degree-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        result = a[i] + x * result;
    }

    return result;
}
```

My compilation flags: `-O1`. Full implementation (including timer) is: https://godbolt.org/z/3eW8Wzr7z

My time cost result:

```
   polyh: took   2.318 ms, loop=10, avg =  0.232 ms
    poly: took  78.980 ms, loop=10, avg =  7.898 ms
```

Why `polyh` run faster with large CPE?

---

update: Based on the comments of @Passer By, I use the website quich-bench for time cost measurement, and with different array size, the benchmark result is different:

n = 1000, `poly()` is faster (https://quick-bench.com/q/EpDmf22VD_E0CvLN0-6TY_Ye8bU)

[image]

n = 10000 , `polyh()` is much faster (https://quick-bench.com/q/yuzoVzz_KhWv1gJ-_j9wlZtfWVM)

[image]

Comment: Horner's scheme should be faster.

Comment: You usually at least use O2, and writing microbenchmarks yourself is really error prone. FWIW [quick-bench](https://quick-bench.com/q/RSBg63JjIIrD428uvr3PrJSE-Lg) also shows Horner's being slower.

Comment: What is not clear from the question: According to the book the CPE values are measured on a specific reference machine/compiler and it mentions when introducing the measurement that it may be different on other machines and compilers. Specifically they seem to be using GCC with `-O1` on an Intel i7 Haswell.

Comment: @PasserBy Yes, I should usually use O2. For this question, I pick O1 due to the book's chapter 5.1 writes "We purposely limit the level of optimization to demonstrate how different ways
of writing a function in C can affect the efficiency of the code generated by a
compiler. We will find that we can write C code that, when compiled just with
option -O1, vastly outperforms a more naive version compiled with the highest
possible optimization levels."

Comment: With O1, [Horner's is still slightly slower](https://quick-bench.com/q/qBZzohhlmO3wQFRRhdDrjkem2Nw) on quick-bench. To make any sense of what the book says, you will need their exact platform and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some confusion regarding the statements in the book. The link you have provided clearly shows `polyh()` to have less CPE than `poly()`:

```
polyh(double*, double, long):
# skipping non-loop code...
    mulsd   xmm0, xmm1
    addsd   xmm0, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rsi - 16]
    add     rsi, -1
    cmp     rsi, 1
    jg      .LBB1_2
```

vs

```
poly(double*, double, long):
# skipping non-loop code...
    movsd   xmm3, qword ptr [rdi + 8*rax + 8]
    mulsd   xmm3, xmm2
    addsd   xmm0, xmm3
    mulsd   xmm2, xmm1
    add     rax, 1
    cmp     rsi, rax
    jne     .LBB0_2
```

Clearly `polyh()` is more precise code in comparission with `poly()`.

Now lets talk about optimization. First of all `-O0` is used to disable optimization. `-01` is the minimum optimizations.

But even if you throw optimization out of the window the code in `polyh()` is optimized before even compilation. It has only 1 of each multiplication, addition and assigment while `poly()` has 2 multiplications and assigments.

Clearly `polyh()` is leaner and farter code.

**UPDATE:**
After updated question here is what I found. I tested with same quick-bench but used GCC instead of CLANG as I was using on my computer, and thee results are still same. `polyh()` wins even with 1000 iterations.

https://quick-bench.com/q/_0IppR0fGBncrR60s5WtUiTq5U8

[image]